# Adapting MultiHostMiddleware for django 2.1+

Tags: python, django, request, response, middleware

I have a single django project with several different apps that are supposed to be hosted on different domains. For example let's call them:

Administrative site, ourdashboard.com

First Content site oursite1.com

Second Content site oursite2.com

Dashboard site is only for content publishers, while content sites are for visitors. Each site is different in terms of functionality, content and design. I want publishers to be able to post content on both sites, so I don't wont to create different django projects. But the genre of the content requires different sites for specific audience.

I started an app called dashboard. I would like this app to be hosted on ourdashboard.com domain, where accessing this domain will directly access `dashboard.urls`. So basically I want to host multiple sites using a single django project, where each domain will be linked to a specific app url file.

I did a little bit of a research, and stumbled upon [MultiHostMiddleware](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/MultiHostMiddleware) and tried to implement it. Looked simple and easy, but having never worked with djangos middleware before, I hit the brick wall right at the start. I properly implemented the code as instructed but I kept getting 500 Internal Server Error. Initially I thought I messed up something in my settings file, but couldn't see where the problem was. Then I looked through logs and noticed that the middleware class was not receiving `get_response`. A little more of the research in [Middleware Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware) showed me that initialization and the callable functions are required and that `__init__` can only receive a single argument 'get_response'. Additionally I learned there were some big changes to djangos middleware not that while ago, and the last update to MultiHostMiddleware was more then 3 years ago (Currently I'm using Django 2.1.5, so post-middleware changes). I've been staring at the old code for 6h now, searching for possible solution, but I'll be honest I don't even know where to start when it comes to middleware. I even thought I could adopt existing functions to required ones, thinking process_response is the callable, since it returns response, but I just fell into another rabbit hole. So, I'm looking for a way to adapt this old code for django 2.1 in order to host different sites using same django project.

**settings.py**

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'network.middleware.MultiHostMiddleware',
    ...
]

HOST_MIDDLEWARE_URLCONF_MAP = {
    "ourdahsboard.com": "dashboard.urls",
    "oursite1.com": "musiclounge.urls",
    "oursite2.com": "artworld.urls",
}
```

**middleware.py**

```
import time
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.cache import patch_vary_headers

class MultiHostMiddleware:

    def process_request(self, request):
        try:
            request.META["LoadingStart"] = time.time()
            host = request.META["HTTP_HOST"]
            #if host[-3:] == ":80":
            #    host = host[:-3] # ignore default port number, if present

            # best way to do this.
            host_port = host.split(':')
            if len(host_port)==2:                    
                host = host_port[0] 

            if host in settings.HOST_MIDDLEWARE_URLCONF_MAP:
                request.urlconf = settings.HOST_MIDDLEWARE_URLCONF_MAP[host]
                request.META["MultiHost"] = str(request.urlconf)
            else:
                request.META["MultiHost"] = str(settings.ROOT_URLCONF)

        except KeyError:
            pass # use default urlconf (settings.ROOT_URLCONF)

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if 'MultiHost' in request.META:
            response['MultiHost'] = request.META.get("MultiHost")

        if 'LoadingStart' in request.META:
            _loading_time = time.time() - int(request.META["LoadingStart"])
            response['LoadingTime'] = "%.2fs" % ( _loading_time, )

        if getattr(request, "urlconf", None):
            patch_vary_headers(response, ('Host',))
        return response
```

** UPDATE **

```
As, requestedstack error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/user/webapps/django_network/network/network/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
     application = get_wsgi_application()
   File "/home/user/webapps/django_network/lib/python3.7/Django-2.1.5-py3.7.egg/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
     return WSGIHandler()
   File "/home/user/webapps/django_network/lib/python3.7/Django-2.1.5-py3.7.egg/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 136, in __init__
     self.load_middleware()
   File "/home/user/webapps/django_network/lib/python3.7/Django-2.1.5-py3.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 36, in load_middleware
     mw_instance = middleware(handler)
 TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'get_response'
```

Comment: can you please share error stacktraces please?

Comment: @ruddra sure thing, added as an update at the bottom of my original post

Answer (score 1):

I think you are writing old style [MIDDLEWARE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware)(which existed till django 1.10), you need to update it like this:

```
class MultiHostMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response


    def __call__(self, request):
        loading_time = time.time()
        request.META["LoadingStart"] = loading_time
        host = request.META["HTTP_HOST"]    
        host_port = host.split(':')
        response = self.get_response(request)
        if len(host_port)==2:                    
            host = host_port[0] 
        try:
            if host in settings.HOST_MIDDLEWARE_URLCONF_MAP:
                request.urlconf = settings.HOST_MIDDLEWARE_URLCONF_MAP[host]
                request.META["MultiHost"] = str(request.urlconf)
                response['MultiHost'] = str(request.urlconf)
            else:
                request.META["MultiHost"] = str(settings.ROOT_URLCONF)
                response["MultiHost"] = str(settings.ROOT_URLCONF)

        except KeyError:
            pass 
        _loading_time = time.time() - loading_time
        response['LoadingTime'] = "%.2fs" % ( _loading_time, )
        if getattr(request, "urlconf", None):
            patch_vary_headers(response, ('Host',)) 
        return response
```

FYI, its a untested code, but it will prevent the error you are facing at the moment.

#### Update

You can update the old style django middleware to new style as per this [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/middleware/#upgrading-pre-django-1-10-style-middleware). I think you can try like this:

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

class MultiHostMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    # rest of the code from your question
```

Comment: Well at least I'm no longer getting any errors. However I'm also not being redirected to proper urls. So far I tested the code and on each domain and request.META['MultiHost'] does indeed return proper urls for those domains (by simply printing request[MultiHost] directly in template), but at the same time, each domain still points to the default ROOT_URLCONF url. And this is the part that's confusing me about middleware, because I think it's response that is causing this error. I don't know how to properly test response contents though, unlike requests contents which I can simply print out.

Comment: @Ablivion I am not sure how this middleware will work, to be honest. I just fixed the error you were facing. :)

Comment: @Ablivion I think you can look into this: https://django-tenant-schemas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use.html

Comment: Unfortunately that one seems to be limited to sudomains, can't find anywhere in documentation how to support two separate domains.

Comment: I don't think so. I think it supports multiple domain.plz check the documentation again. Thanks

Comment: finally got it working, [django-hosts](https://django-hosts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) solved the problem